# Proxy Error from backend API to frontend react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/products from
localhost:3000 to http://192.168.137.1:4000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ETIMEDOUT).

this error keep on coming.
Frontend -> React
Backend-> Express, nodejs

Comment: You can try adding `"proxy": "http://192.168.137.1:4000"` to your React app's **package.json**.

Comment: that's already done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed `"proxy": "http://192.168.137.1:4000"` to `"proxy": "127.0.0.1:4000"` and this worked for me now...

This is done on windows

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue but in the Mac machine. I changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and that worked for me.

For Windows:

```json
"proxy": {
  "/auth/google": {
    "target": "localhost:5000"
  }
}
```

For Mac:

```json
"proxy": {
  "/auth/google": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
  }
}
```

Comment: Still same error